# PHPExcel won't recalculate

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my excel file, I have `B1=IF(A1>0,"Greater than Zero",IF(A1<0,"Less than Zero","Equal Zero"))`.
I tried to retrieve `B1` information via `getCalculatedValue` after changing the `A1` value.

I did this multiple times, but both echos return "Less than Zero"
I don't understand why the second echo doesn't return "Equal Zero?"

```
/** Change A1 Value **/
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','=-1');

/** Calculate and State B1 Value **/
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue();

/** Change A1 Value AGAIN **/
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','=0');

/** Calculate and State B1 Value **/
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue();
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9142966/570812

Comment: Thank you both so very much. That took care of my problem.

Comment: Should I flag this as a duplicate? (although I don't think it is exactly the same quesiton.) or should I simply delete this quesiton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPExcel caches the results of formula calculations by default to improve performance, so the second time you call `getCalculatedValue()`, it will return the cached value rather than recalculating. If you have changed the underlying data, then you need to clear the calculation cache before calling `getCalculatedValue()` again, in order to retrieve the updated calculated value for the same cell.

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->clearCalculationCache();
```

Alternatively, disable calculation caching completely:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->disableCalculationCache();
```

Comment: Thanks, am I right in saying flushInstance is for clearing all cache, and clearCalculationCache is only clearing, well, calculation caches?

Comment: Nope, they're simply synonyms

Comment: `PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->clearCalculationCache(); // For PHPExcel version >= 1.7.9`

Comment: CrandellWS, Mark Baker, Thank you, guys! Everything works fine